# What is the highest practical Dropbox quota and number of files stored?

Tags: dropbox

I have a Dropbox for Business account with a 1000GB quota, and they said they would increase the quota if I need more. But they did say that performance might degrade if I have a very large number of files. Has anybody observed this performance drop, and at what number or volume of files?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming they are talking about the Dropbox application on your computer experiencing performance issues with a large number of files, and not that your teams account would experience any degraded performance server side.  I currently have over 100,000 files and have not experienced a drop in performance.  I have heard of people with much more, I believe at least 400,000.